# Infinite list filtering does not work in a Django app

Tags: django

Creates the simplest infinite list that expands when it reaches the end of the page. My code looks something like this:

**views.py**

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

    query = Product.objects.all()    

    #paginator
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(query, 21)
    try:
        numbers = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        numbers = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        numbers = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

in the template I use it this way:

```
<!-- products list -->
<div class=" infinite-container">
  <!-- product query -->
  {% for product in numbers %}
    <div class="accordion accordion-spaced infinite-item">
      <h1>{{ product }}</h1>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
  <!-- end query -->
</div>

<!-- Load more -->
{% if numbers.has_next %}
  <div class="mt-4 text-center">
    <a href="?page={{ numbers.next_page_number }}" class="btn infinite-more-link">Loading...</a>
  </div>
{% endif %}
<!-- end pagination -->

<!-- Infinite Scroll -->
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/infinite.min.js' %}"></script>
<script>
var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
  element: $('.infinite-container')[0]
});
</script>
```

If I try to add filtering by category, it works only for the first page, and the next items that showed after expanding are incorrect (it shows what should not).
I do it this way:

```
query = Product.objects.all()
sort = request.GET.get('sort', False)
if sort:
    query = query.filter(category=sort)
#[... other elements in the view without changes ...]
```

How can I apply filtering to an infinite drop-down list to make it work properly on every page?

[How I create a drop down list, all files.](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/13/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-with-django.html)

Maybe this will make it easier to show a vivid example. My website
https://tgwebsite.com/opinie/#all_reviews

https://tgwebsite.com/opinie/?sort=Google#all_reviews (first page filtered, next ones don't work properly, in this case only red reviews should show up.)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue today. The infinite scrolling samples online do not combine well with Django standard filtering.

You will need to modify the href value to include the category filter value.

For example in your code:

```
<a href="?category={{request.GET.category}}&page={{ numbers.next_page_number }}" class="btn infinite-more-link">Loading...</a>
```

If you have a CSRF token in the filter form, you would have to add it to the URL too.

Comment: Please accept this answer. Works perfectly.